# How to give Customer Community users access to specific record types on a custom object?

Tags: community

I have a custom object called Applications. I want Customer Community users to only be able to access and edit records of a specific record type of Applications in our Community. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The base Customer Community license cannot do this without custom development.  I have implemented my own access checks in apex to solve similar issues.  I found this post that might help you also:  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=906300000004384AAA